# Fine tune the characterization of measurable sets in the case of finite outer measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

This is a statement from Carothers' Real Analysis

> Suppose that $m^*(E) < \infty$. Then, $E$ is measurable if and only
> if, for every $\varepsilon >0 $, there exists a compact set $F \subset E$ such that $m(F) > m^*(E) - \varepsilon$

"===>" is easy. Since we can make use of the following Corollary preceding this statment in the book

> Corollary. If $E$ is measurable, then we also have  $$ m(E) =
> > \sup\{m(K): K \subset E \text{ and }  K \text{ is compact } \}  $$

How to prove the other side "<===="???

Note that there are two equivalent definition of a set being measurable.

1. Carathéodory criterion: $\forall A \subset \mathbb{R}$, we have $m^*(A) \geq m^*(A \cap E) + m^*(A \setminus E)$.
2. Using open sets/closed sets to approximate.
   $\forall \varepsilon > 0$, there exists an open set $G \supset E$ such that $m^*(G \setminus E) < \varepsilon$. **OR** $\forall \varepsilon > 0$, there exists an closed set $F \subset E$ such that $m^*(E \setminus F) < \varepsilon$

Which way I should adopt?

**UPDATE April 18.**

Thanks to Mason's comment. This question can be solved by using another equivalent definition of a set being measurable, that is:

3. $\forall \varepsilon > 0$, there exists an open set $G \supset E$ and a closed set $F \subset E$ such that $m^*(G \setminus F) < \varepsilon$

Comment: The assumptions imply that there exist compact sets $K_n \subset E$ such that $m(E) = m(\bigcup_n K_n)$. Since $m(E)$ is finite, this implies that $E$ is the union of a Borel set and a null set, so $E$ is Lebesgue measurable.

Comment: You mean $m^*(E)$? That doesn't make sense to me. You only get $m^*(E) - m(\bigcup_n K_n) = 0 $, you don't get $m^*(E \setminus \bigcup_n K_n) = 0$

Comment: @Mason Sorry I forget to tag you

Comment: Yeah you are right. We can use $m^*(E) = \inf\{m(U) : U \text{ is open and } U \supset E\}$ to conclude that for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there exist $U \supset E$ open and $K \subset E$ compact such that $m(U \setminus K) = m(U) - m(K) \leq 2\varepsilon$. Then we apply similar arguments to get borel sets $A \supset E$ and $B \subset E$ such that $m(A \setminus B) = 0$.

Comment: @Mason You mean we get $m^*(A \setminus B) = 0$ ,then we have $m^*(A \setminus E) \leq m^*(A \setminus B) =0 $. Also note that A is a $G_\delta$ set so we are done?

Comment: We get $E = B \cup E \setminus B$ is the union of a Borel set and a null set, so we are done.